# could not create the java virtual machine Tomcat server error

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have to add this configuration  `-Xms40m -Xmx2048m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -` to VM arguments in launch configuration proprties , but when I add it and I try to start tomcat v6.0 server a could not create the java virtual machine appears .
what should I do ?

Comment: Do you close the pervious server? Which may cause a port conflict.

Comment: I just have one server

Comment: Can you paste the error log ?

Comment: I have added this configuration  -Xms40m -Xmx2048m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m and the problem is solved